# Store last login timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, reporting

I have a Java application that connects with a MySQL database.

I want to add reporting to this application. The first thing i want to track is when are people logging in.

For this I have create a `lastlogin` column in my table. When the user successfully logs in i update it

`update mytable set lastlogin=Now() where userid='xxxx'`

1) Is there a better way to do it? There are many people login into the app.

2) Can MySQL automatically update the timestamp everytime a row is accessed?

3) Is there Reporting library that i can use instead that will do most of the work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

The TIMESTAMP data type offers automatic initialization and updating to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp)

Comment: would the TIMESTAMP only update on insert or update or would it also update on SELECT? It really needs to update on SELECT.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza TIMESTAMP columns work for updates as well. From the link above: "If the column is auto-updated, it is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value." If lastlogin is the only column being updated when the user logs in, then there's no advantage to using TIMESTAMP. But it can save some code if you want to update the timestamp when other column is updated.

Comment: @codeNinja No, it would only be for INSERT or UPDATE. If lastlogin is the only column you're updating, then the code you have is probably optimal.

Comment: @codeNinja but OP will only update this column. AFAIK keep track of user login or action is based on insert approach, not on update approach. Even if you track if a user updated a table, you insert the action and the user into a new table.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider creating a new record in some sort of history table on each login.  That way you can see all logins instead of just the last one by timestamp.  Create a new table `mytable_login_history` and insert into it upon every login:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable_login_history` (`user_id`, `date_created`) VALUES (xxx, NOW());
```

where `xxx` is the user ID